# Extraer imagen de base de datos

Tags: vb.net, unity

Necesito extraer imágenes de una base de datos para después mostrarlas en `unity` y cuando hago la consulta intento guardar la imagen en un array de bytes pero no funciona. Además luego el problema esta en pasar ese array a una imagen visible.

```
<WebGet()>
<WebMethod()>
<OperationContract()>
Public Function prueba() As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.TableName = "Foto"
    dt.Columns.Add("foto")

    Dim s As String = "SELECT dbo.comedores2.mesa FROM dbo.comedores2"

    Dim SqlComman As String = s.ToString
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SqlComman, New SqlConnection(conexion))
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        ds.Tables.Add(table)
        cmd.Connection.Close()
    End Using

    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("mesa")
        dt.Rows.Add(byteArray)
    Next

    Using dt
        Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
        Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow! Dos preguntitas un poco tontas, pero en la base de datos (parece SQLServer) la columna "mesa" de que tipo es? Si inspeccionas `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("mesa")` de que tipo es? P.D. Podría ayudarnos mucho si nos indicas el error que tienes y la línea donde ocurre.

Comment: porque pones el tag de c# si el codigo que publicas es vb.net ?

Comment: @frikinside la columna mesa es de tipo "image"  y no es que me de error solo que no se como puedo guardar esa columna de alguna forma para despues poder visualizar otra vez la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente, desconozco los funcionamientos o requerimientos propios de `Unity` para la tarea que estás realizando. Por lo que he podido revisar depende mucho de si es un sprite, si es una textura, ect...

No obstante, igual si puedo ayudarte con la parte técnica de `vb.net` y decirte como puedes formatear ese array de bytes en una codificación que puedas utilizar.

### 1- Convertir la imagen en un `StringBase64`

Al ver que estás usando un `JavascriptSerializer` es posible que puedas pasar la imagen en dicho formato.

Para convertir el array de bytes en un `StringBase64`, lo haríamos de la siguiente forma:

```
Dim byteArray As Byte() = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("mesa")
Dim imageStringBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)
dt.Rows.Add(imageStringBase64)
```

### 2- Convertir el byte[] en un objeto imagen

Otra opción que te podría ser interesante es la de crear un objeto imagen:

```
Dim imagen as Image
Dim memoryStream as System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)
imagen = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
```

Como comentaba al principio, lamentablemente mis conocimientos de `Unity` son puramente conceptuales y revisando el código que nos proporcionas no he visto en que tipo de objeto de unity necesitas guardar la imagen para intuir cual sería el formato requerido. No obstante, la primera opción me parece que tiene potencial con lo poco que puedo conocer de ello. Alguien que sepa de `Unity` seguramente te pueda indicar correctamente, esperemos que esta respuesta al menos pueda servir para intentar indicarte el camino correcto.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN 2017/04/27 16:27

Estuve revisando y para asociarle a un game object una imagen hay que crear un objeto de tipo `Texture2D`. Los objetos `Texture2D` tienen un método `LoadImage` que te pide que le pases una imagen en `StringBase64`, por lo que la opción primera nos podría valer. Sería algo así:

```
Dim byteArray As Byte() = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("mesa")
Dim imageStringBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)
Dim texture2D as Texture2D() = New Texture2D(1, 1)
texture2D.LoadImage(imageStringBase64)
```

Nos faltaría un paso adicional, que es crear un `sprite` partiendo de esa textura que acabamos de crear (aportación de [joniggi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/39787/joniggi)):

```
Sprite sp2 = Sprite.Create(texture2D, new Rect(0, 0, ancho, alto), new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f)); 
miPrefab.transform.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sp2;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad ;) probare lo que me has dicho he intentare mirar en foros de unity. En principio queria guardarlo en un gameObject que tenga componente image.

Comment: @joniggi Nada, no hay problema. Realmente, creo que sería más oportuno que alguien con conocimiento suficiente de Unity te pusiera la respuesta de forma más correcta, pero si mientras esto te puede ir sirviendo de ayuda o incluso para llegar a la solución bienvenido sea! Tampoco lleva la pregunta mucho tiempo, esperemos que con suerte alguien con experiencia en Unity te pueda echar un cable. Hice una actualización en la pregunta en base a la documentación que leí sobre el `gameObject` a ver si te puede servir.

Comment: Al final consegui gracias a tu ayuda poner esa imagen en Unity. Lo ultimo que me hizo falta fue crear un sprite a partir de esa Textura y ya luego asignar ese sprite o  "imagen en unity" al objeto imagen que ya tenia.

Comment: Sprite sp2 = Sprite.Create(texture2D, new Rect(0, 0, ancho, alto), new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f));                                          miPrefab.transform.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sp2;                             Graciasss!!

Comment: @joniggi no sabes cuanto me alegro de oír eso. Voy a añadir ese último paso a la respuesta para que quede correcta y sea útil para consulta. Acéptala como respuesta marcada para que la solución quede verificada por favor.